# Error:The name ChromiumWebBrowser does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

i am getting message 
The name ChromiumWebBrowser does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf

```
 <Window x:Class="Sample1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="625"
     WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"  
      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">

<Grid>
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0" Address="http://google.com/" />

</Grid>
```

when i run this project it is working but when i creating setup file then it is not working.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612449/the-name-chromiumwebbrowser-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespacecefsh/47031708#47031708

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#5-why-does-the-visual-studio-wpf-designer-not-work-when-i-add-a-chromiumwebbrowser-to-my-app for information on designer warning. It's usually safe to ignore if the project compiles.

The fact that it's not working when you create a **setup** is likely totally unrelated. If your using `Click Once` then there are extra steps required. There are numerous issues on the `GitHub` project page that cover the issue.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/search?q=click+once&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1314
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/500

If your using another installer then the general information is likely still relevant, you need to have the installer include the unmanaged dependencies.