# The name ChromiumWebBrowser does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces, cefsharp

I had followed this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881315/Display-HTML-in-WPF-and-CefSharp-Tutorial-Part) to implement CefSharp applicaton.

But I have stuck while coding `MainWindow.xaml`.

Blend for VS 2015 said,

> The name ChromiumWebBrowser does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"

But I'm installed CefSharp.Common and CefSharp.Wpf v51.0.0, cef.redist.x64 and cef.redist.x86 v3.2704.1432 with NuGet Package Manager.

I'm new on developing C# so I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me to solve this error.

This is my `MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="StocktalkBrowser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StocktalkBrowser"
        xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0"  Address="https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Comment: Does it just say it as info, or it doesn't compile ? Sometimes the designer is really stupid and just tell you things, but the project will compile without any problem. Perhaps Clean your project and rebuild. Sometimes that also helps

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I tired it many times, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Does it compile ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Would you tell me where is defined clr namespaces?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada no, It doen't.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Oh Sorry, it compiles but when I run output file, it stops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried the link, and as I mentioned in the comments it compiles without any problem.

[image: It is shown as error, but you can ignore it]
Can be ignored.

[image: No Preview available]
And the preview is not available as well, I learned to live with it.

[image: Compiles]
No errors when compiling

[image: Program starts]
And the program starts up. No problem

Comment: I don't know why, but it is running well now ! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that the solution platform was set to AnyCPU.
As far as I know, CefSharp does not support AnyCPU. Interestingly the solution ran just fine in Release mode, but in Debug mode I immediately got an error - `the invocation of the constructor on type that matches ... the specified binding constraints threw an exception.`

As soon as I changed the solution platform to be only x64, then the XAML error went away (`The name ChromiumWebBrowser does not exist in the namespace “clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf”`). And I could run the solution both in Debug and Release mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I retired using CdefSharp and moved to Electron. I'll try it again when I have time enough. Thank you Marko

Answer (score 0):

its not supported in the XAML desginer, so load it in run time:

1. Remove the element from the XAMl, and instead place any container such as a Border:

   ```
   <Border x:Name="cefChromeContainer" />
   ```
2. in the Constructor code, after `InitializeComponent();` call, craete the browser element and place into the container. even better to declare the browser in the class scoop:

   ```
   CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser();

   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       cefChromeContainer.Content = browser;
       browser.Address = "https://stackoverflow.com";
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! but we chose Electron insteat.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solve it changing configuration to from "*debug*" to "*release*" and using "*x64*" as platform.

But it was not enought to change it from the solution menú, as i usually do. You need to go to visual studio main menú under "**Compile > Configuration administration**", as you can see in the following link from *Microsoft*:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#Anchor_0

This solution was in fact in the Readme.txt file for cefsharp, as stated in the "Documentation" link provided by **saschad** in his answer: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/69/NuGet/Readme.txt

There you can read it:

> - For `x86` or x64`set your solution target architecture to`x86`or`x64`, just changing the project is currently not enough (See
>     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx#Anchor_0 for
>     details).

Now I have it running like a charm :D

Answer (score -1):

You can read in the ([Documentation](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/69/NuGet/Readme.txt)) of the NuGet package, it's also necessary to add an `app.manifest` to your Application.